# RXJS subscribe only if previous value is not that great and I really need a better one

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a costly server ajax request which has one input (`full: boolean`). If `full` is `false`, the server can return either a partial or a full response (`response.isFull == true`); but if `full` is `true`, the server ***will*** return a full response. Normally the partial response is good enough, but there are certain conditions that will require a full response. I need to avoid requesting a full response explicitly as much as possible, so I thought I'd start with a `BehaviorSubject` which I can eventually feed with `true` and combine it with `distinctUntilChanged` if I ever need to get the full response. This will give me an observable with `false` initially and that can give me `true` if I feed that into it:

```
const fullSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Then I've got a function that takes a boolean parameter and returns an observable with the server request (retried, transformed, etc.). As said, the answer can be partial or full, but it can be full even if the input parameter was false at the server's discretion. For example:

```
interface IdentityData {
    ...
    isFull: boolean;
}

private getSimpleIdentity(full: boolean): Observable<IdentityData> {
    return Axios.get(`/api/identity${full?"?full=true":""}`)
    .pipe( ... retry logic ...,
        ... transformation logic ...,
        shareReplay(1) );
}
```

I need to know how can I combine these so that the following is true:

- The server needs to be queried at most twice.
- If the first answer is a full answer, no further queries must be performed to the server.
- If the first answer is a partial answer, and `true` is fed into `fullSubject`, a full answer must be requested.

The expected output from all this is an observable that emits either one full response, or a partial response and, when asked, a full response.

Environment: Vue 2.6.11, RxJS 6.5.5, Axios 0.19.2, TypeScript 3.7.5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: these requirements don't make much sense to me.  if you NEED a full response, why do you waste resources by making an indeterminate query first? Why not just request the resource you need? If you're already aware of the type of resource you need, why ever bother with more than one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

```js
const fullSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);

const src$ = fullSubject.pipe(
  switchMap(isFull => Axios.get('...')),
  take(2), // Server required at most twice
  takeWhile(response => !response.isFull, true), // When `isFull`, it will complete & unsubscribe -> no more requests to the server
  shareReplay(1),
);

src$.subscribe(() => { /* ... */ });

function getFullAnswer () {
  fullSubject.next(true);
}
```

`takeWhile` takes a [second argument](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeWhile.ts#L8), `inclusive`. When set to true, when the predicate function evaluates to false(e.g isFull is true) it will send that value as well. –

Comment: Sounds about right, I'll check it immediately. This helps me a lot. Only one thing remains: how can I share these answers among several subscribers without creating new requests? `shareReplay(1)` at the end would break the logic, I suppose.

Comment: If you want to subscribe to “src$” in multiple places without firing multiple requests, I’d say you could add shareReplay after ‘takeWhile’ without any issues

Comment: So, `shareReplay` worked just fine, but `takeWhile` will ignore the answer with `response.isFull`. I've set up a variable outside of the pipe and used `prev = savedFull; savedFull = newFull; return prev` inside the `takeWhile` condition. I don't know if there's a better way?

Comment: Oh, and `getPartialAnswer()` is not required, as the `BehaviorSubject` already starts with false.

Comment: Glad you asked! `takeWhile` takes a [second argument](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeWhile.ts#L8), `inclusive`. When set to `true`, when the predicate function evaluates to false(e.g `isFull` is `true`) it will send that value as well.

Comment: Great! Can you edit the answer to include these comments, so I can accept it?

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I've got it correctly

```
private getSimpleIdentity(): Observable<IdentityData> {
  return fullSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(full => Axios.get(`/api/identity${full ? "?full=true" : ""}`)),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
}
```

Uses the **retryWhen()** operator

```
const source = of("").pipe(map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)));

const example = source
  .pipe(
    tap((val) => console.log("tap", val)),
    map((val) => {
      //error will be picked up by retryWhen
      if (val !== 5) throw val;

      return val;
    }),
    retryWhen((errors) =>
      errors.pipe(
        tap(() => console.log("--Wait 1 seconds then repeat")),
        delay(1000)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((val) => console.log("subscription", val));

/*
  output:
  tap 3
  --Wait 1 seconds then repeat
  tap 8
  --Wait 1 seconds then repeat
  tap 1
  --Wait 1 seconds then repeat
  tap 4
  --Wait 1 seconds then repeat
  tap 7
  --Wait 1 seconds then repeat
  tap 5
  subscription 5
*/
```

Comment: I don't understand. How can I inject the BehaviorSubject into retryWhen?

Comment: give me an input and output to what you want to do

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better than I did. I'm thinking of making a diagram, but I'm not sure how that would work.